# Remove Element based on attribute using XSLT

Tags: xslt

I am in need to hide the element, when the attribute is present in the entry. When attribute cols is present, then the remaining empty entries should be hidden in the same row. When attribute morerows is present, then entry present in the next row of same column, should be removed.

Sample Input:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<table>
<tbody>
<row>
<entry cols="2">Row 1 Col 1</entry>
<entry></entry>
<entry></entry>
<entry morerows="2">Row 1 Col 4</entry>
<entry>Row 1 Col 5</entry>
</row>
<row>
<entry>Row 2 Col 1</entry>
<entry>Row 2 Col 2</entry>
<entry>Row 2 Col 3</entry>
<entry></entry>
<entry>Row 2 Col 5</entry>
</row>
<row>
<entry>Row 3 Col 1</entry>
<entry>Row 3 Col 2</entry>
<entry>Row 3 Col 3</entry>
<entry></entry>
<entry>Row 3 Col 5</entry>
</row>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<table>
<tbody>
<row>
<entry cols="2">Row 1 Col 1</entry>
<entry morerows="2">Row 1 Col 4</entry>
<entry>Row 1 Col 5</entry>
</row>
<row>
<entry>Row 2 Col 1</entry>
<entry>Row 2 Col 2</entry>
<entry>Row 2 Col 3</entry>
<entry>Row 2 Col 5</entry>
</row>
<row>
<entry>Row 3 Col 1</entry>
<entry>Row 3 Col 2</entry>
<entry>Row 3 Col 3</entry>
<entry>Row 3 Col 5</entry>
</row>
</tbody>
</table>
```

XSLT tried:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:m="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:mml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()"><xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/></xsl:copy></xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="row">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:for-each select="entry">
<xsl:if test="@cols"><xsl:variable name="span_cols" select="@cols+1"/></xsl:if>
<xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[$span_cols]"/>
</xsl:for-each>
<xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="entry">
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="@cols">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:variable name="current_colno" select="count(preceding-sibling::entry)+1"/>
<xsl:variable name="span_cols" select="@cols+1"/>
<xsl:attribute name="namest"><xsl:value-of select="$current_colno"/></xsl:attribute>
<xsl:attribute name="nameend"><xsl:value-of select="sum($span_cols,$current_colno)"/></xsl:attribute>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise><xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy></xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet
```

>

Comment: Do the `@cols` and `@morerows` attributes only exist in the first `<row>`, or could they be anywhere?

Comment: @ABach: Thanks for your reply `@cols` and `@morerows` could occur any where and it may contain any values also

Comment: You have used `version="2.0"` in your code, does that mean you can use an XSLT 2.0 processor like Saxon 9 or AltovaXML to solve that?

Comment: @MartinHonnen: I can use XSLT 2.0 and Saxon 9he version

Answer (score 1):

I have written some code which tries to implement the transformation in three steps:

1. flag those `entry` elements to be deleted because of a `cols` attribute
2. flag those `entry` elements to be deleted because of a `morerows` attribute
3. finally remove the flagged `entry` elements

Here is the code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()" mode="#all">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* , node()" mode="#current"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tbody">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:variable name="cols-flagged-to-delete" as="element(tbody)">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="flag-to-delete-col"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="rows-flagged-to-delete" as="element(row)*">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$cols-flagged-to-delete" mode="flag-to-delete-row"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$rows-flagged-to-delete" mode="delete"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tbody/row" mode="flag-to-delete-col">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="entry" group-starting-with="entry[@cols]">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="self::entry[@cols]">
          <xsl:variable name="cols" as="xs:integer" select="xs:integer(@cols)"/>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()[not(node()) and position() gt 1 and position() le (1 + $cols)]"
             mode="flag-to-delete-col"/>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()[position() gt (1 + $cols)]"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tbody/row/entry" mode="flag-to-delete-col flag-to-delete-row">
  <entry delete="true"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tbody" mode="flag-to-delete-row">
  <xsl:for-each-group select="row" group-starting-with="row[entry/@morerows]">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="self::row[entry/@morerows]">
        <xsl:variable name="pos" as="xs:integer" select="count(entry[@morerows]/preceding-sibling::entry) + 1"/>
        <xsl:variable name="n" as="xs:integer" select="xs:integer(entry/@morerows)"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()" mode="flag-to-delete-row">
          <xsl:with-param name="pos" select="$pos"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="n" select="$n"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tbody/row" mode="flag-to-delete-row">
  <xsl:param name="pos"/>
  <xsl:param name="n"/>
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="position() gt 1 and position() le (1 + $n)">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="entry[position() lt $pos]"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="entry[$pos]" mode="flag-to-delete-row"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="entry[position() gt $pos]"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="entry"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="row/entry[@delete = 'true']" mode="delete"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However I have only tested that on the small sample you have provided, so when I use Saxon 9.5 to transform

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <row>
      <entry cols="2">Row 1 Col 1</entry>
      <entry></entry>
      <entry></entry>
      <entry morerows="2">Row 1 Col 4</entry>
      <entry>Row 1 Col 5</entry>
    </row>
    <row>
      <entry>Row 2 Col 1</entry>
      <entry>Row 2 Col 2</entry>
      <entry>Row 2 Col 3</entry>
      <entry></entry>
      <entry>Row 2 Col 5</entry>
    </row>
    <row>
      <entry>Row 3 Col 1</entry>
      <entry>Row 3 Col 2</entry>
      <entry>Row 3 Col 3</entry>
      <entry></entry>
      <entry>Row 3 Col 5</entry>
    </row>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I indeed get

```
<table>
  <tbody>
      <row>
         <entry cols="2">Row 1 Col 1</entry>
         <entry morerows="2">Row 1 Col 4</entry>
         <entry>Row 1 Col 5</entry>
      </row>
      <row>
         <entry>Row 2 Col 1</entry>
         <entry>Row 2 Col 2</entry>
         <entry>Row 2 Col 3</entry>
         <entry>Row 2 Col 5</entry>
      </row>
      <row>
         <entry>Row 3 Col 1</entry>
         <entry>Row 3 Col 2</entry>
         <entry>Row 3 Col 3</entry>
         <entry>Row 3 Col 5</entry>
      </row>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

But more complicated input and output samples are needed I think to test the code, so please do that and report back. And I have assumed there is not more than one `morerows` attribute inside of the `entry` elements of each `row` element, I am not sure that assumption holds for your input requirements.

Comment: Apology for the late reply. I tested your code and its working fine for current XML. But I could not delete entry elements when more than one morerows attribute occur as you said

Comment: I think it works as long as there is a single `entry` with a `morerows` attribute per `row`. However more work is needed if there can be more than one `entry` with a `morerows` attribute per `row`. I won't have time to try to solve and implement that, sorry. Maybe someone else is able to assist you.

Comment: Thanks for your great effort and timely help. I will try to modify by myself. I really appreciate your help in this regards.